# Combining sentences without using "that" or "which"

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

I am struggling to combine the following two ideas into one complete sentence:

> 1. High number of missed cycles can be seen from site1.
> 2. Missed cycles mainly occurred due to the missing segments (complete objects).

This is my effort on this.

> Missed cycles in site1 were mostly due to the missing of segments (complete objects).

I want to improve this further. Any further rectifications please. 
Additionally, do I need to put the definite article in front of "missed cycles"?

Comment: in 2nd sentence, I have change the term 'missing' into missed to refer to same entities.

Comment: 1) Proofreading is off topic on ELL; this question barely passes that mark because you ask if you need "the" before "missed cycles". If you have concerns about this sentence, please post exactly what you think might be wrong and why. (If there are other problems they will be pointed out in answers, I assure you.) 2) In your combined sentence, you don't seem to have included the information from sentence 1; you never mention that a hight number of cycles were missed. So I think you need to add that information.

Comment: Try: "The high number of missed cycles in site1 are mostly attributed to missing segments (complete objects)."

Answer (score 1):

You changed the tense from missing to missed. This might not be what you want. A missed cycle has a different meaning than missing.

A simple way to combine 1. and 2. would be:

> A high number of missed cycles can be seen from site1, mainly due to
>   missing segments (complete objects).

You can refine the sentence a bit more:

> A high number of missed cycles on site1 were mainly due to missing
>   segment (complete objects).

I removed the 'can be seen' since that is not usually necessary and is often a clumsy way of saying something.

The final wording will depend on the context and the audience.

Answer (score 1):

Your effort sentence changed *missing* to *missed*, which may not be what you intended. Also, you are correct that beginning your sentence with "The" is better. I would advise refining the sentence to something like:

> The missing cycles, seen in site1, were mainly caused by missing segments (complete objects).

If you would like an explanation of the reasons for any of the changes I made please comment on this answer and I will respond.